# Linux : add android platform to cordova

Tags: android, linux, cordova, addition

When I add **android** platform to my project by issuing the command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get the following error :

```
Unable to fetch platform android: Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/mo3tssem/tmp/npm-13061-R9BWhlB2'
```

Comment: if you are on ubuntu try `sudo cordova plaform add android`

Comment: Do you have the riight to access this directory?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so your **/home/ubuntu/tmp** has wrong permissions. It happened because you did **sudo npm install** in the past, and npm doesn't handle this well enough.

Run **sudo chown ubuntu /home/ubuntu/tmp -Rv** to fix this issue, or just delete that folder.

Comment: I don't understand the "/home/ubuntu/tmp " did you try to say ~/tmp?

Answer (score -1):

run this first:

```
ln -s /tmp $HOME/tmp
```

Comment: always consider illustrate why he have to do the steps listed in your answer, i.e, why he has to run this first