# Apache Cordova - Error in adding platform

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build an android app using Cordova. When I try to add any platform to the project , it gives a weird message

```
"lokesh@algo1:~/hello$ cordova platform add android
 Unable to fetch platform android: Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/lokesh/tmp/npm-20721- 
 vboL12Ej'
```

I have tried for more than two hours searching to the extent possible but didn't find any thing useful.
Please help me .Below are my attempts like exporting proxy , paths .....[image]

Comment: As [this comment suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335523/linux-add-android-platform-to-cordova#comment41335732_26335523), does using `sudo` (`sudo cordova plaform add android`) help at all?

Comment: @admdrew Thank you, it worked .But when I try to compile it , it says
  ant -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /home/lokesh/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Any idea ?